# How to make a trouble shooting program in visual basics?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a troubleshooting program. so far i have the following code:

```
Public Class speakers

    Dim currentq As Integer
    Dim Q1 As String = "Does sound play?"
    Dim Q2 As String = "Has the sound got too much bass or treble?"
    Dim Q3 As String = "Is the sound too loud or quiet?"
    Dim Q4 As String = "Is sound distorted?"
    Dim Q5 As String = ""
    Dim Q6 As String = ""
    Dim Q7 As String = ""
    Dim Q8 As String = ""

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If currentq = 0 Then
            Label1.Text = Q1
            currentq = 1
        ElseIf currentq = 1 Then
            Label1.Text = Q2
            currentq = 2
        ElseIf currentq = 2 Then
            Label1.Text = Q3
            currentq = 3
        ElseIf currentq = 3 Then
            Label1.Text = Q4
            currentq = 4
        ElseIf currentq = 4 Then
            Label1.Text = Q5
            currentq = 5
        ElseIf currentq = 5 Then
            Label1.Text = Q6
            currentq = 6
        ElseIf currentq = 6 Then
            Label1.Text =
            currentq = 7
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        currentq = currentq + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Controls.Clear()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

How would you make a label change one question to another when you click on either the yes or the no button

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'currentq = 0 here , so it shows the next question          
    LoadNextQuestion()
 End Sub


 Public Sub LoadNextQuestion()
    If currentq = 0 Then
        Label1.Text = Q1            
    ElseIf currentq = 1 Then
        Label1.Text = Q2
    ElseIf currentq = 2 Then
        Label1.Text = Q3
    ElseIf currentq = 3 Then
        Label1.Text = Q4
    ElseIf currentq = 4 Then
        Label1.Text = Q5
    ElseIf currentq = 5 Then
        Label1.Text = Q6
    ElseIf currentq = 6 Then
        Label1.Text = Q7
    End If
 End Sub
```

now in the no / yes button :

No Button :

```
'Loads next question
currentq += 1 
LoadNextQuestion()
```

Yes Button :

```
Controls.Clear()
InitializeComponent()
Me.Hide()
Form1.Show()
```

Comment: the code can be modified in many ways that will do the same job , also you are welcome ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this...

```
Public Class speakers

    Dim currentq As Integer
    Dim questions() As String = {
        "Does sound play?",
        "Has the sound got too much bass or treble?",
        "Is the sound too loud or quiet?",
        "Is sound distorted?",
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d"
    }

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Button4.PerformClick()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        currentq = currentq + 1
        If (currentq < questions.Length) Then
            Label1.Text = questions(currentq)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("End of questions reached.")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        currentq = -1
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End Sub

End Class
```